# What are Scripts in League of Legends

Tags: league-of-legends, terminology, cheats

I was playing a game not too long ago and our mid player got completely destroyed. He was accusing the other player of scripting. Maybe he was wrong and just a sore loser, but it's not the first time I hear this.

What is scripting?

It seems to be an automation system to improve your damage output through cheating, perhaps also to dodge skillshot.

What do scripts do? Are there many different types?

How is Riot not detecting this kind of "script"?

Comment: This sounds like someone trying to justify their loss. Scripts for complex games like this rarely benefit in the heat of play, at the end of the day a script must be prepared prior to events playing out therefore they cannot react as well as a human. Some scripts slip through Riots defenses, but often not for long. Also to note, mostly these are 'bots' that you can find lurking in AI matches to farm IP, however these follow set, simple patterns of play and pretty much always get decimated by the real AI opponents

Comment: Scripts, generally speaking in gaming environment, are usually a sort of "hacks" that allow you to do certain actions in sequence through a single click.

 They are more common in dota, since Dota does have more complicated combos. 
Its probably just a rant from a toxic player.

Comment: In all likelihood, the player is just angry. I say "hacks" sometimes if I feel someone just super-outplayed me, but it's [tongue-in-cheek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tongue-in-cheek).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Scripting is basically when software takes over the control over some actions like combos (Brand Combo etc.). Some scripts can even dodge nearly every skillshot or level up your smurf to level 30 on its own.

There are actually two types of scripts.

### - Champion Scripts

Scripts that will pull off hard mechanical plays for you. They only work for certain champions. E.g. ryze skill rotation, when his passive is up (root every 2 seconds) etc.

### - Utility Scripts

Utility scripts are scripts that affect your gameplay in general and not for a specific champion.
There are Utility Scripts, which will not be considered as cheating by riot.

For example a script which extends your HUD with a spotify interface so you can change the playing song ingame.

On the otherside there are scripts like automatic jungle timing, ultimate timing, orbwalking assistance, dodging assistance, "last seen"- position of the enemy champions visible on the map and even scripts that will level up your smurf to level 30 in Co-Op vs AI games.

I'm not sure what riot does against scripters I guess they don't get banned really often but I'm not sure.

Comment: They get banned in mass waves every couple weeks/months

Comment: ... It's all about gameplay advantages. Timers and Spotify controls are fine (even though there are already built-in timers) but auto-levelers (or botting in general) and macros are a no-go.

Answer (score 2):

Scripting in a cheating sense is basically anything that automates player controls such as macroing combos, jungle timers, and other things such as a player's last know location. There are also skillshot dodging scripts and bot scripts that allow a player to gain unfair advantages and farm to level 30 without putting effort into it.

Macroing chat is confirmed to be fine (so having a button press for "Mid Flash" is acceptable) but that is basically the extent to what Riot allows.

Comment: Agreed. Anything that gives a gameplay advantage that other players don't have is generally forbidden.